# Not seeing Google Play Services rev 15 in SDK Manager (yet) for Google Cast SDK

Tags: android, sdk, google-cast

As per the [Cast SDK Docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads), to use Cast SDK in Android I need, Google Play Services Revision 15.

I dont see Rev 15 in my SDK Manager. Can anyone else see it yet? or know by when we can expect to start developing for Android with rev 15? Is there an alternative stop gap to get around the problem till Google pushes out to all SDK Managers?

Comment: Did anybody got update of Google Play Services Revision 15??

Comment: I still don't have it ...

Comment: The r15 update is now available through SDK Manager.

Comment: Happy coding now... :) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can anyone else see it yet?

No, because it is not yet available.

**UPDATE**: OK, now it is. Let the downloading commence!

> or know by when we can expect to start developing for Android with rev 15?

On [the page that you linked to](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads), in a large yellow box, you will find:

> Developing with the Google Cast Android APIs requires Google Play services 4.2, which began rolling out to devices worldwide on February 3rd. **Once the update to devices is complete**, the corresponding Google Play services library (revision 15) will be available for download from the Android SDK Manager.

(emphasis added for emphasis, emphatically)

Note that today is February 3rd, which means the Play Services rollout just began today.

> Is there an alternative stop gap to get around the problem till Google pushes out to all SDK Managers?

You can wait patiently. Or wait impatiently, if you prefer.

Comment: So when they say they've released the Cast SDK, they haven't actually released it at all. Sigh.

Comment: They released the documentation. That's like an SDK, right?

Comment: @PhilKulak: The documentation documents the not-yet-released SDK. Please read my answer, particularly the quoted passage from that documentation.

Comment: They released it for iOS.

Comment: @AlexGilleran I was being sarcastic. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah this is kinda lame.  It's been two days.

Comment: Been four days now...anyone else seeing the rev 15 update in the SDK Manager?

Answer (score 2):

I believe AllCast "speaks" the Google Cast protocol (RAMP) and does not use the API.  He probably sniffed it and reversed engineer it, much like others have with the AirPlay protocol.

So, if you are motivated and good with WireShark, you can do the same!  Personally, I'm holding out for the API, most impatiently.

Sorry.  I still can't comment, so I have to post everything as Answers (stupid rule)

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for this library too and I didn't find it yet but why Allcast has one? I installed google play services 4.2 on my phone and then i installed allcast from google play and it works very nice. So why we can't get access to this library too? It is not fair we have been waiting for long time too! And why it is available first for iphone :(

Comment: The author of AllCast found a way to interface with a Chromecast many months ago, but then Google pushed out a firmware update that broke all home-brewed apps. They've now added official support for such apps, so AllCast is able to work with Chromecast again without waiting for the library update. As for the rest of us, I agree — it's an awkward rollout.

Answer (score 1):

It will take couple of weeks to release as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/cast-developer/answer/4529018?hl=en&ref_topic=4512233).

So we have to wait till couple of weeks more.

Comment: How are these Apps being released with Chromecast functionality if the SDK has not been released? http://androidspin.com/2014/02/05/new-chromecast-supported-apps-go-live-play-store/?utm_content=bufferc1a7a&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Comment: @user1406716: I don't know that... But in the link given by you last 3 apps were made by google. One is `Tic-Tac-Toe`, and rest are powered by `YouTube`.

Answer (score 0):

Google just released it. Check the SDK manager for an updated version of Google Play services (rev15).