# Google play service 4.2 available in USA?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cast

i'm trying to find the google play service 4.2 in the SDK which is a rev 15 as per google. But, I see only rev 14 in the SDK manager. Do I have to do something special to get the latest version? I'm trying to get the chrome-cast SDK.

[image]

Comment: What version is Google Play Services Rev 15? I try to put: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
in the dependencies of build.graddle but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available now. Please update it from the sdk manager. thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

> You'll be able to get started with the new APIs as soon as the Google Play services rollout is complete -- a process we expect to take several days. We'll then release the updated Google Play services SDK and you'll be able to download it through the Android SDK manager. Watch for more information coming soon.

Taken from the [Official Android Developers Community](https://plus.google.com/108967384991768947849/posts/B93cTTEjCXv)

Comment: If you check the link here they said it will be out on Feb3rd . https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads . "Developing with the Google Cast Android APIs requires Google Play services 4.2, which began rolling out to devices worldwide on February 3rd. "

Comment: Once the update to devices is complete, the corresponding Google Play services library (revision 15) will be available for download from the Android SDK Manager. (Taken from your link)

Answer (score 0):

I do not see it either: [Related Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540238/not-seeing-google-play-services-rev-15-in-sdk-manager-yet-for-google-cast-sdk/21584080#21584080)

It is said that all devices need to be updated first.

**Updated 2/14**: Google Play Services update rev 15 is available in the SDK Manager as of yesterday.