# Google Play Services SDK not showing up

Tags: android

I'm using eclipse and would like to use the Google Play Services SDK in one of my projects. However, when I look at the Android SDK Manager, I can't seem to find it. See below.

[image]

Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: I see you have not updated to the rev 23, Did you check from the SDK manager tools menu?

Comment: @ByzantineFailure what do you mean?

Comment: Open the SDK manager, click on tools > Options > Force Https:// make this checked. Let us know if that works!

Comment: I dont have an "Options" under "Tools"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled everything and this seemed to fix itself.

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't see google play services in my development machine. I am using windows. It look like while updating google will not allow google-play-service to download. Please refer to @commonsware answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540238/not-seeing-google-play-services-rev-15-in-sdk-manager-yet-for-google-cast-sdk?answertab=votes#tab-top).